# Reflection- viewpager not working after the application of reflection

Tags: android, reflection, android-viewpager

I am trying to use reflection in my app. i have created one common method which hits the **API** on request of different classes.

```
 public static void hitUrl(final Activity activity, String url, HttpMethod httpMethod, final String classname) {

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(httpMethod.getMethod_identifier(), url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.i("Response", response);

            if(classname.equals(DashboardActivity.class.getSimpleName())){
                ((DashboardActivity) activity).responseString(response);
            }


           /* try {
                Class classname = Class.forName(componentName);
                Object classobject = classname.newInstance();
                Method method = classname.getMethod("responseString", String.class);
                method.invoke(classobject, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

This is the method i call from a different class.

This is how i call it.

```
ApiMethods.hitUrl(this, newurl, ApiMethods.HttpMethod.GET, TAG);
```

Then this is how i parse the response and set up the viewpager. The response is coming and the log is also displayed.The problem is viewpager shows NPE at the line

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_dashboard);




 public void responseString(String tabcategories) {
    Log.i(TAG, "Tab categories " + tabcategories);
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(tabcategories);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String names = object.getString("name");
            info.put(names, object.getInt("id"));
            Log.i(TAG, "map: " + names + " " + info.get(names));
        }

        setupViewPager();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When i use this the `viewpager` in the class gives a NPE at this line

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager_dashboard);
```

If i don't use reflection then this is working.
What could be the problem?

Comment: show your error log and how you use this with your viewpager

Comment: The log error is null pointer exception at the above line. And i just sent the volley response and set up the view pager after parsing it.

Comment: can you post more related code , can not get a conclusion for now..